# Resize Canvas when resizing Main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to resize a canvas that is include into a TabControl, I want it to resize when I resize the window at execution time

I tried to resive the canvas using event SizeChanged and then scale it but it is not working, it does not resize the elements inside the canvas, that are rectangles, they just disappear when I make the window smaller

This is the XAML code I am using

```
<Window x:Class="practica_final.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:customer_purchases"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Customer" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Name="btnCustomer" Content="Add Customer" Margin="10" Click="btnCustomer_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
            <Button Name="btnExit" Content="Exit" Margin="10" Background="Tan" Click="btnExit_Click"/>
            <Button Name="btnHelp" Content="Help" Margin="10" Click="btnHelp_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TabControl Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TabItem Name="tabItemCustomer" Header="Customer">
                <Canvas Name="canvasCustomer" Background="LightYellow"
                            SizeChanged="canvasCustomer_SizeChanged"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Name="tabItemPurchases" Header="Purchases">
                <Canvas Name="canvasPurchases" Background="CornflowerBlue"
                            SizeChanged="canvasPurchases_SizeChanged"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the MainWindow.xaml.cs I have the sizeChanged code

```
namespace customer_purchases{  
    public partical class MainWindow : Window {      
        private ScaleTransform sc;
        private TranslateTransform tt;
        private TransformGroup tg;

        public MainWindow() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sc = new ScaleTransform();
            tt = new TranslateTransform();
            tg = new TransformGroup();
            tg.Children.Add(tt);
            tg.Children.Add(sc);
        }

        [...]

        private void canvasCustomer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            width = canvasCoche.ActualWidth;
            height = canvasCoche.ActualHeight;

            tt.X = 10;
            tt.Y = 10;

            sc.ScaleX = ancho / 20;
            sc.ScaleY = alto / 20;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried including the Canvas into a ViewBox but I couldn't see the results properly when executing it

Comment: do you want to scale everything in the canvas or do want toexpand your canvas?

Comment: I want to scale everything, now I can expand my canvas but the content doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to listen to any size chaned events just use a viewbox around your canvas like this:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Background="Lime">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="20" Height="10" Width="10" Fill="hotpink"/>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

the canvas will strech its content to the size of the parent, however it is important to hard-code the canvas size to make this work as expected.